# How to set heights of column elements using bootstrap?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, grid

So what I'm trying to do is set the starting heights for two different columns. For the first column I want it to occupy 30vh and the second column to be 70v, but I also want both columns to fill up 100vh when expanded above a breakpoint of medium and above. The tricky part is getting the columns at the starting breakpoint to be 30vh and 70vh which I tried by giving the columns a class and setting the height in a seperate css, but then when I do that it stays that size when I go above medium. I tried setting the height on the ROW bootstrap element with h-100, and it changes the height of the row to be 100% but If i try to do anything other than h-100 it doesn't apply any changes.

```
   <div id="main-page" class="container-fluid "> 
        
    <div class="row h-100">
      <div class="col-sm-6 bg-primary">col-sm-8</div>
      <div class="col-sm-6 bg-secondary">col-sm-4</div>
    </div>
   
  </div>
```

```
#main-page {
    height: 90vh;
    background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.1);
}
```

https://www.malai.co/
This website is what I'm trying to aim for.

Comment: Don't really understand your problem. So you want two columns at full height (100vh no scroll or just min-height=100vh) from tablet screen up and one column with two div at 30/70vh when in mobile screen?

Comment: Yeah. The website I posted has what im going for, with slightly different vh's i presume.